# fundamental group and covering space

Tags: algebraic-topology, riemann-surfaces

I have a question about the fondamental group of 
the following covering space

$$
p : Y \rightarrow X ; \; Y \owns (x,y) \mapsto x \in X
$$
where $X = {\mathbb P}^1$ and

$$
Y := \{(x,y) \in {\mathbb C}^2 : y^2 = (x-a_1)(x-a_2)(x-a_3)(x-a_4)\}.
$$

Denote a closed path on $X$ based at $x_0$ encircling $a_i$ once by $\gamma_i$. 
Then we have

$$
\pi_1(X,x_0) = \{[\gamma_1],[\gamma_2],[\gamma_3],[\gamma_4] 
: [\gamma_1][\gamma_2][\gamma_3][\gamma_4]=1\},
$$
where $x_0 \in X$ and $[\gamma_i]$ is the homotopy class of $\gamma_i$.

We identify $Y$ with a torus 
by cutting the surface of $X$ along lines from $a_1$ to $a_2$ and $a_3$ to $a_4$
and pasting two copies of them along the lines.

We denote the meridian circle and the latitude cicle of the torus 
by $\alpha$ and $\beta$ respectively.
Then,

$$
\pi_1(Y,y_0) = \{[\alpha],[\beta]\ \; : \; [\alpha][\beta][\alpha]^{-1}[\beta]^{-1}=1 \},
$$
where $y_0 \in p^{-1}(x_0)$.
Then,
$$
p_*([\alpha]) = [\gamma_1][\gamma_2], \; p_*([\beta]) = [\gamma_2][\gamma_3].
$$

Combining the condition $[\gamma_1][\gamma_2][\gamma_3][\gamma_4]=1$, we have

$$
\gamma_3 \equiv \gamma_1 {\rm mod} \; p_* \pi_1(Y,y_0), \; 
\gamma_2 \equiv \gamma_4 \equiv \gamma_1^{-1} {\rm mod} \; p_* \pi_1(Y,y_0) 
$$

But I cannot derive 
$$
\gamma_1^2 \equiv 1 \; {\rm mod} \; p_* \pi_1(Y,y_0),
$$
which I think necessary to complete the conditions.

Could someone help me?